# problem in extension class

Tags: apex, visualforce

Here is my Apexclass

```
public  class Orgfinhist {
   public OrgFinHist__c mcc {get; private set;}
   public Orgfinhist (ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
       mcc = (OrgFinHist__c) sc.getRecord();
   }
}
```

and my visualforcepage name: org

```
<apex:page standardController="OrgFinHist__c" extensions="Orgfinhist ">
  hello
   <apex:form>
     <apex:page>
     <apex:inputField value="{!mcc .name}"/>
     </apex:page>

   </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

and error displaying:Error: Unknown property 'mcc' referenced in org

Comment: Remove the apex:page tags that surround the apex:inputField; they may be hiding the attributes of the outer (correct) apex:page tags.

Answer (score 4):

Like Keith said before, you don't need the extra page tags around the input field.

```
<apex:page>//remove this line
  <apex:inputField value="{!mcc .name}"/> // <--remove extra space {!mcc.name}
</apex:page>//remove this line
```

Since you are using an input field, you have 2 choices.

1) Use the standard controller object.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!OrgFinHist__c.Name}" />
```

2) Make the setter public

```
public OrgFinHist__c mcc {get; set;}
```